# При нажатии на отладчик в pycharm выдает ошибку "Failed to find uploads for the local path '-mpydevd'"

Tags: python, pycharm

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: Ошибка]
Даже при попытке старта отладчика на стандартном коде pycharm выдает данную ошибку.
пробовал создавать сторонний проект ошибка сохранилась

Answer (score 0):

Удалось решить проблему самостоятельно переустановкой python и переустановкой pycharm(с выставлением всех галочек и перезагрузкой устройства)